# Prove by using Pigeon Hole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $k \in \mathbb Z^+ $. Prove that there exists a positive integer $n $ such that $k|n$ and the only digits in $n$ are 0's and 3's

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Let $$m_n=\underbrace{3\dots3}_{n\text{ threes}}\;.$$ Let $r_n$ be the remainder when you divide $m_n$ by $k$. Use the fact that if $r_n=r_\ell$ with $n>\ell$, then $k\mid m_n-m_\ell$.

Comment: the digits in $m_n$ are only 3 or consist on 3 and 0 ?

Comment: @chihiroasleaf: The digits of $m_n$ are all $3$’s. Note that you’re only required to find a number that has no digit **other than** $0$ and $3$: it need not have both $0$ and $3$. However, in many cases the number that you get from this hint won’t be one of the $m_n$’s, and it will have both $3$’s and $0$’s.

Comment: @chihiroasleaf Said differently, consider the set {3, 33, 333, 3333, ...., (3 repeated k times)}. Now, any number when divided by k can give remainders between 0 and k - 1. Now, divide each number in the given set with k and observer the remainders that they give. What happens if one of the remainders is zero and what happens if none of the remainders are zero?

Comment: is this correct?

I make $k+1$ $m_n$ they are
$m_1$ = 3
$m_2$ = 33 
.

Comment: @chihiroasleaf: Yes, two of $m_1,\dots,m_{k+1}$ must have the same remainder. Now what can you do with them to get a multiple of $k$ that has only $3$’s and maybe some $0$’s?

Comment: is this correct?

I make $k+1$ $m_n$ they are
$m_1$ = 3
$m_2$ = 33 
.
.
.
$m_9(k+1)$ = 33...33 (k+1 digits of 3)

if we divide each number by $k$ , then there exists $n,l \in \mathbb Z^+ $ where m_n and m_l have the same remainder 
so $r_n = r_l=r$

let $m_n = q_1 *k + r$ and $m_l = q_2 *k +r*
so $m_l - m_n = (q_2 - q_1 ) k$ 
so $k| m_l - m_n$ 
we chose the number $m_l - m_n$

Comment: @chihiroasleaf: That’s right, provided that $\ell>n$. Do you see why it will work? It will have $\ell-n$ $3$’s followed by $n$ $0$’s.